# functional vs class components on react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please advise which of the two is better
And which one should I use to get started?
And which is better in terms of ease of implementation and efficiency
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is no strong reason to start a project using class, for the following reasons:

- Class has been deprecated by facebook itself;
- Using function you can use hooks, which is one of the best things that have been inserted into react, being able to help you in state control, variable value changes and significant performance improvements;
- Code readability and organization;
- You don't need to be extending components anymore;

There are more reasons, but the biggest in my opinion are hooks, using this type of function and behavior in a class was extremely complicated, especially when we were going to use contexts.

Hope I could have helped you!